# Prevent Finder from restoring previous tabs?

Tags: macos, finder

For some reason Finder always restores all my previously open tabs even after I've restarted the system. This is unnecessary for me and in just several days my Finder is really clustered up and I had to close the tabs one by one. There must be a setting to disable such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You have the option at Shutdown or Restart for whether or not to reopen windows...
though it does include whether to reopen Apps, too

[image]

If you want only the Finder to not save its state, try this in Terminal

`defaults write com.apple.finder ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES`

You can revert the setting using `NO` instead of `YES`

Comment: That's not what I mean. I don't click this option and Finder doesn't automatically reopen upon restart. However, whenever I *manually open* Finder again, it immediately displays all the *tabs* that were previously on in the last session.

Comment: Why are you closing/quitting Finder anyway? If you restart it, it will normally use its previously saved state, from `/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState` Adding a terminal command to my answer,to prevent Resume, but I'm not sure if it works for Finder, you'll have to test it